# AngularJS expression in Razor tag helper

Tags: angularjs, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I try to use an AngularJS expression in a Razor tag helper, like this:

```
<a asp-controller="Foo" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="{{myAngularControllerInstance.selectedFooId}}">Edit</a>
```

But the AngularJS expression is not expanded. What is the correct syntax? Is it even possible? Are there alternatives?

Comment: "asp-route-id" resolved at server side, but angular expression resolved (expanded) at client side. You cannot use it like this.

Comment: No ! It does not work that way. Your razor code (input tag helper calls) will be executed in server and output will be rendered to client browser where the js code (Angular) will be executed at a later time

Comment: Yeah that's what i suspected.... So what would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove tag helpers and it will work !.

```
<a href="Foo/Edit/{{myAngularControllerInstance.selectedFooId}}">Edit</a>
```